# In Visual Studio, where are environment variables defined?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

In Visual Studio, where are variables such as the below defined ?
[image]

I have looked everywhere in the project, including at solution level, but I cannot find anything

Comment: In the `.vcxproj` file, or one of the `.props` or `.targets` files included by it. See [.vcxproj and .props file structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcxproj-file-structure?view=msvc-160) for some pointers.

Comment: Thank you, I am building using VC19 from a github repo that uses solution files for vc14: https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib, and I guess VC19 did not import that variable properly. Where can I define it ? Do I need to edit the files manually ?

Comment: I am not familiar with that particular project, but maybe see [Set compiler and build properties / User-defined macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=msvc-160#user-defined-macros).